# How to close my single tab

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website in php(YII).
I have a task of subscription renew in it by paypal.
I have completed that task and after it i redirect link from paypal to "profile.php" named page.

My problem is - in some condition I want to close this tab. I have only single tab for this task, means no popup or child tab.
I used for this task is :

```
window.close();
close();
window.top.close();

{
window.open('','_parent',''); 
window.close();
}
```

etc but it didn't work because i have only single tab.
so please help me.

Thanks,

Comment: go to this url http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/ClosingWindowsNotOpenedByJS.html

Comment: but it cant close in case of single tab. i have already tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You may raise Ctrl+W event manually through javascript. this closes the tab in all the modern browsers(FF,GC,IE).

```
var evt = jQuery.Event("keypress");
evt.keyCode = 87; // w
evt.ctrlKey = true;
$(document).trigger(evt);
```

Comment: i want it by coding, so what is that?

Comment: ok your code looking good but how to use it - in any function or only in script?
because i used it by putting it in script and also pressed w but didn't worked. :(

Comment: Just gonna say that OP wanted JAVASCRIPT solution, while you provided strictly JQuery one. 
It will take longer in simple js.